# Get Xamarin Forms control actual width in code behind

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Here is my Xamarin Forms XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ToggleIndicator" HorizontalOptions="FillandExpand" HeightRequest="4" />
```

I would like to get this control's width in code behind. `ToggleIndicator.HeightRequest` returns `4` which makes sense, however, how would I be able to get the actual width? `ToggleIndicator.WidthRequest` returns `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is the width is changing from -1 to whatever, on rotation etc.. so:

```
   <Grid 
              SizeChanged="ToggleIndicator_OnSizeChanged"
              x:Name="ToggleIndicator" HorizontalOptions="FillandExpand" HeightRequest="4" />
```

codebehind:

```
private void ToggleIndicator_OnSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as Grid;
    if (grid != null)
    {
        //check my grid.Width
    }
}
```